# c++/cli assembly loads a C# component that spawns multiple CLR threads; how do I stop those threads from re-entering the C++/CLI entry point?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winapi, c++-cli

I have a C/C++ application architected with the following components

1. Native C/C++ application (single-threaded message pump, typical Win32 UI app), which statically links (2)
2. Native C/C++ Lib/DLL which dynamically loads (3) at run-time
3. A C++/CLI DLL compiled with /clr which wraps a C# assembly (4)
4. A C# assembly which uses TPL and has background timers, all exposed via static singleton methods

My issue is this: C# assembly spawns asynchronous I/O threads in response to calls from the parent app and uses a pair of System.Threading.Timer instances in the background.

These threads keep attaching the the native C/C++ application (1) and are causing some side-effects, such as COM initialization issues.

Here's what the output Window looks like when the C# component is running, and I can see those threads attach to the C++/CLI DLL (3) entry point when it runs.

[image: C# threads exiting on native C/C++ application]

My question is: how to I firewall these C# threads from the C/C++ application? I don't want those threads to be able to keep calling the entry point of the native code that loaded it.

So far the best work-around we've been able to come up is running all of the code that calls the C++/CLI / C# dlls (3 and 4) in their own separate Win32 thread (which works), but I would appreciate any other suggestions!

Comment: I'm having trouble following the problem; can you try to summarize it?

Comment: Not sure this is relevant but "[do not call CoInitialize, CoInitializeEx, or CoUninitialize from the DllMain function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms695279%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is entirely normal.  Your [DllMain() entrypoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) gets called whenever a thread starts running.  Doesn't matter who originated the thread, it happens both for threads started by native code as well as managed code.  You'll get the `DLL_THREAD_ATTACH` notification when the thread starts running.  `DLL_THREAD_DETACH` when it stops running again.

The *intention* of these callbacks is to help you setup thread-local storage.  You normally entirely ignore them.  You can ask Windows to not bother with it, call [DisableThreadLibraryCalls()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682579%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in your DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH notification handler.

This is purely meant as an optimization, not as a bug workaround.  There is no conceivable scenario where these callbacks should ever cause COM problems, I doubt you truly discovered the source of your problem.  Unless your DllMain() function is ignoring the `fdwReason` argument, that would be bad.